# Assign Int value to sprite node

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

In my game, I have the same node added many times repeatedly to move across the screen. This node has a SKLabelNode child with text either "1" or "2". I want to be able to assign a number value of either 1 or 2 depending on the text of the label. Using the code below I set a value for a key but I didn't know how to relate this with my node to be able to check for it. Does anyone have a simpler way of doing this or have anyway to fix my existing code?

```
 if theLabel.text == "1" {

            var userDefaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()

            number = userDefaults.integerForKey("number")

            userDefaults.setValue(1, forKey: "number")

        }

        if theLabel.text == "2" {

            var userDefaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()

            number = userDefaults.integerForKey("number")

            userDefaults.setValue(2, forKey: "number")

        }
```

Comment: where and when do you need to access this value? There are certain situations where this would be the best way to store a value. For instance, if you wanted to set a value for a setting in your app that would remain after termination.

Comment: @M321K  I need to check for the value in didBeginContact, so I could differentiate between the same nodes who's child labels have different texts when there is a collision. so for example i could check if there is a collision involving the node and also check whether the value of the node was 1 or 2.

Comment: ok yeah theres a better way to do that, check out my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If inside `didBeginContact` you wanted to check what text was inside of a child labelNode, you should first specify a name for the labelNodes when you initialize them:

```
theLabel.name = "labelNode"
```

this will suffice. Now, inside of your `didBeginContact` method you probably already have something like this in order to check for contact:

```
var firstBody: SKPhysicsBody
var secondBody: SKPhysicsBody

firstBody = contact.BodyA
secondBody = contact.BodyB
```

And you probably already know that to access the sprite node associated with each body you just specify for example `contact.BodyA.node`. So, all thats left is to find the child node of `contact.BodyA.node` with the name `"labelNode"`. You can do that like this:

```
var labelNode: SKLabelNode = contact.bodyA.node.childNodeWithName("labelNode") as SKLabelNode
```

Ok now that you have your label node you can easily check its text and do whatever you want:

```
println(labelNode.text)
```

Now you just do the same thing with bodyB. Hope this helps!